# How to make Selenium IDE as exe?

Tags: javascript, plugins, exe, selenium-ide

I downloaded Selenium IDE code.Now i want to start selenium IDE just by double clicking on it not as firefox plugin.Any Idea which helps me to start IDE as a desktop application is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has noted; Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin and has no executable equivalent at this time; however, you could create a shortcut that launches the Selenium IDE as soon as Firefox launches.

You can do this by passing the Selenium IDE chrome XUL to the -chrome argument accepted by the Firefox executable:

```
"firefox.exe" -chrome chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-ide.xul"
```

On Windows, you could create a shortcut, place that snippet in the Target field, and then change the shortcut's icon. This could easily be automated by an installer. If you seriously need an executable, then there may be a Firefox Web Browser control, or something equivalent that you can embed in a window.

Comment: Again, as others have said, if you seriously need to decouple Selenium IDE from Firefox, then you have a massive project ahead of you.

Comment: Hi Chris,is it possible to decouple IDE from firefox using Firefox Web Browser control? ?

Comment: If you are using C#/VB.NET you could take a look at this project; I am not sure about plugin functionality. You may need to also embed/implement an XUL wrapper for .NET. http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Comment: Is it possible to open selenium ide and automatically run given selenium script?

Answer (score 1):

It is a Firefox plugin, so you can't start it as a desktop application. You could launch Firefox from an icon and load it?

> [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) is an integrated
>   development environment for Selenium
>   scripts. It is implemented as a
>   Firefox extension

Comment: I know to start firefox and selenium IDE by creating shortcut on desktop.I want to write some code in IDE that makes Selenium IDE firefox independent.HOW can it be done.Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't (or not without a huge amount of work). It's essentially an in-browser tool and requires a browser to operate. Currently that browser is Firefox, I guess in theory it could be replaced by some other browser but that would be a vast change. What do you wish to accomplish by having it as an independent tool? Why is it being dependent on Firefox an issue for you?

Comment: Its the given requirement from our company.  I don't even know how to start with it...

Comment: What do you need to do with the Firefox independent Selenium IDE? It really isn't clear what you're asking for here. It doesn't make any sense for Selenium IDE to not be working with a browser. Do you need it to work with Internet Explorer? What do you expect to happen when you launch the Firefox-independent Selenium iDE?

Comment: It should be compatible with all the browsers and also support more features which are not supported by present IDE.

Comment: It should work with all the browsers but should not be firefox dependent ie as a plugin. My test cases should run in all browsers...

Comment: My point is, just seperate IDE from firefox ,rest the functinality of Selenium IDE should be same..

Comment: Then this is a huge project, and you should be talking to the Selenium iDE development team http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is a Firefox plug-in and can't be run stand-alone.

However, you can run [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) aka Selenium RC.

This in invoked by a command line parameter e.g.

> java -jar selenium-server.jar

Just make a shortcut which you can then double-click.

**Note:** A quick way to get the Selenium RC basics is to load the Selenium IDE, capture your test, click "Options / Format" and then select the type of output you require. You can see a sample [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2010/10/selenium-rc-importing-script-from.html)