# Selenium equivalent for Windows OS

Tags: windows-7, selenium, automation

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957654/how-to-make-selenium-ide-as-exe), I wanted to ask if there is any program in windows 7 available, that could record events like

1. Clicked start button
2. Launched Netbeans
3. Clicked Options
4. Entered Value

...etc?

And then play it again so that I dont have to reconfigure something everytime or many other use cases like that?

Thanks

p.s. I am being more specific here and no intention of duplicating any post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty.

Free, you can use an application like [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) It has great documentation and we currently use it for iOS and Android application automation.

Professional/Enterprise tools are available from the usual vendors, [IBM Rational suite](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/), [HP's WinRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_WinRunner) that serve all sorts of purposes.